# MongoDB $unset operation for array fields

Tags: mongodb

I have collection of documents with following structure:

```
_id
date
computers [
    users [
        name:
        surname:
        age:
    ]
]
```

What I want to do, is to remove field 'name' from all documents (names of all users for all computers). $unset operation works perfectly for non-array fields, e.g.:

```
db.collection.updateMany( {}, { $unset: {"date": ""} })
```

but when I try to access field 'name' with:

```
db.collection.updateMany( {}, { $unset: {"computers.users.name": ""} })
```

value of modifiedCount parameter in Robo 3T = 0. Is it even possible to perform such operation?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you can try using the [positional identifier](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) like this:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{},
{
  "$unset": {
    "computers.$[].users.$[].name": ""
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P3VgVnSueV7)

Comment: I finally managed to find it in the documentation yesterday, but anyway thank you very much for the answer :)